# Where can I find the .db file created by sqlite3 on an android app created by buildozer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, kivy, buildozer

I wanted to make an android app using kivy but I wasn't sure if the sqlite3 module would work so I made a small program that displays a word and adds it to a database however when I ran the app I couldn't find any .db file to view its contents and the app has permission to access storage and it takes up storage in the internal storage but I can't find the .db file so does anyone know where it would be? Or if sqlite3 doesn't work on android then what module would work?

I also found that the python-for-android module has a recipe for sqlite3 at this link
 https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/sqlite3

So should I do something when converting from .py to .apk?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe that the `db` file will be created in `/Android/data/package_name/` where `package_name` is the `package.domain` and `package.name` from the `buildozer.spec` file. The file may be restricted access.  To use `sqlite3`, just add `sqlite3` to your `requirements` in the `spec` file.

Comment: Yeah I tried to find it but couldn't and I already added the sqlite3 to requirements

Comment: You could just provide a full path to a public folder for the sqlite command.